# Is there a way to select levels of a factor for analysis

Tags: r, lme4

trt has four levels, 0,A,B,C. Is there a way to only include A, B,C during analysis?

```
df <- lmer(formula= df[,i] ~ trt +(1|id), data=df)
```

Comment: Do you need to `subset` the data?  `droplevels(subset(df, trt %in% c("A", "B", "C")))`

Comment: That could be a way! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We can `subset` the data and remove the unused levels with `droplevels`

```
df1 <- droplevels(subset(df, trt %in% c("A", "B", "C")))
```

and us that data in `lmer`

---

Or as the author of the package `lme4` (@BenBolker) commented, there is a `subset` argument in `lmer`.  Not sure if the `droplevels` is needed for that

```
library(lme4)
lmer(formula= df[,i] ~ trt +(1|id), data=df, subset=(trt!="0"))
```

Comment: or `lmer(..., subset=(trt!="0"))`